# Berlekamp Massey and DFT

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, coding-theory

I was looking into the Berlekamp Massey algortihm, for LFSR, over GF(2) wondering if there 
  was any DFT(alternately FFT), for the above scheme. Also, is there any generalization to 
  Fn, ie, start with GF2, and if there exists a DFT for the same, and to extend the the same
  for a Field over n. To be specific I may be given a sequence 0,1,1,0,1, and to find the 
  min poly using BM, and DFT or FFT.

Answer (score 2):

The book *Theory and Practice of Error-Control Codes* by R. E. Blahut (Addison-Wesley, 1983) and its second edition *Algebraic Codes for Data Transmission*
(Cambridge University Press, 2002) have extensive discussions about finite-field Fourier transforms and their application in working with the Berlekamp-Massey
algorithm. Since the Berlekamp-Massey calculations are additions of polynomials
(that is, addition of vectors whose entries are the coefficients of the polynomials), and since Fourier transforms are linear transformations
from $\mathbb F^n$ to $\mathbb F^n$, the additions can be carried out in 
either domain.  Thus the books talk about implementing the Berlekamp-Massey
algorithm in the time domain or in the frequency domain, etc. which seems
exactly what you are looking for.

To answer the questton you ask in your comment, the computation of 
the *syndrome* for BCH codes is effectively computing,
in part, the finite-field Fourier transform of the received sequence.
Applying the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to the syndrome yields the
error-locator polynomial (and the error-evaluator polynomial) for
the received sequence. So the calculations do indeed use DFTs (and
even FFTs if convenient). As Blahut's books point out, these ideas
extend to the complex field as well.

Comment: Thank you for input, at first chance will look at the books for reference, but to get an outline, could this be a sequence for a FFT for the Berlekamp Massey:     Input - vector X in C^2^n(complex field), and Output - Vector Y such that this is an FFT for the error locator poly, the error at the position k is w(cube root unity)^(ik) - I am assuming this but may be wrong, just a starting point, but any outline/input as how the FFT may work, (even for a GF2 sequence)?